# A question about Square integrable martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

Let $\left\{X_{n}, \mathcal{F}_{n}\right\}_{n \geq 0}-$  square integrable martingale, and
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}\right)^{2}<\infty.
$$

If exists Random variable $X_\infty$.

Want to prove
$$
\mathrm{E} X_{\infty}^{2}<\infty, \quad X_{n} \rightarrow X_{\infty} \text { a. s. } ,\quad \mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{\infty}\right)^{2} \rightarrow 0
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by if there exists $X_\infty$, do you mean that tehre exists a random variable such that $X_{n} \rightarrow X_{\infty} \text { a. s. }$ ? This hypothesis is not clear since it's in your conclusion

Comment: I think that means there exits $ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n=  X_\infty.$ but need to prove why $X_{n} \rightarrow X_{\infty}$ a. $\mathrm{s}$

Comment: But the pointwise limit is stronger than the a.s. limit

Comment: yep, a.s. is weaker than the lim, and i dont know how to explain, maybe its only told us the $X_\infty$ exists, and need to prove the a.s. relationship with the $X_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full answer note that we need to use martingale property

So as mentioned in my comment above under hypothesis lets show that $X_n$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ which is a Banch space and os is complete :
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}\right)^{2}<\infty$$

So at $\epsilon >0$ fixed there exist $N_0$ s.t. for $n,p > N_0$:

$$\mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{p}\right)^{2}=\mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}+X_{n-1}- ... +X_{p+1}-X_{p}\right)^{2}=\sum_{i=p+1}^n \mathrm{E}\left(X_{i}-X_{i-1}\right)^{2}$$

the reason for that is the following :
if $n=p+1$ then :
$$\mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{p}\right)^{2}=\mathrm{E}\left((X_{n}-X_{n-1})+(X_{n-1}- X_{n-2})\right)^{2}=\mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}\right)^{2}+$$
$$\mathrm{E}\left(X_{n-1}-X_{n-2}\right)^{2}+ 2.\mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}\right).\left(X_{n-1}-X_{n-2}\right) $$
But $\mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}\right).\left(X_{n-1}-X_{n-2}\right)=0$ as from martingale property :
$\mathrm{E}(X_{n}-X_{n-1}).(X_{n-1}-X_{n-2})=\mathrm{E}(X_{n}X_{n-1}) - \mathrm{E}(X_{n-1}^2)+\mathrm{E}(X_{n-1}X_{n-2})-\mathrm{E}(X_{n}X_{n-2})$

$$=\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{E}(X_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})X_{n-1}) - \mathrm{E}(X_{n-1}^2)$$
$$+\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{E}(X_{n-1}|\mathcal{F}_{n-2})X_{n-2}) -\mathrm{E}(\mathrm{E}(X_{n}|\mathcal{F}_{n-2})X_{n-2})$$
$=\mathrm{E}(X_{n-1}.X_{n-1}) - \mathrm{E}(X_{n-1}^2)$ (using (1) below)

$+\mathrm{E}(X_{n-2}.X_{n-2}) -\mathrm{E}(X_{n-2}.X_{n-2})$ (using (1) below)
$$=0+0$$

So by recurrence and as the series is convergent we are assured that at fixed $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N_0$ such that for every $n,p> N_0$ we have :

$$\mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{p}\right)^{2}=\mathrm{E}\left(X_{n}-X_{n-1}+X_{n-1}- ... +X_{p+1}-X_{p}\right)^{2}=\sum_{i=p+1}^n \mathrm{E}\left(X_{i}-X_{i-1}\right)^{2}<\epsilon $$

The $X_n$ is Cauchy in a complete space $L^2$, which entails existence of a limit $X_\infty$ up to almost sure equivalence class and everything in your conclusion holds true without further ado.

(*) This is true as for $n>k$ and $X \in \mathcal{F}_{n}$, the conditional expectation of $X$ knowing $\mathcal{F}_{k}$ is the (only) r.v. $Z\in\mathcal{F}_{k}$ s.t. for every $Y$ in $\mathcal{F}_{k}$ we have :

$$\mathrm{E}(Z.Y)=\mathrm{E}(X.Y)$$ (1)

Then such a $Z$ is denoted $\mathrm{E}(X|\mathcal{F}_{k})$ and it's unique almost surely.

Regards

Comment: Just a remark. 
For proving $E(X_n-X_p)^2 = \sum_{i=p+1}^n E(X_i-X_{i-1})^2$, you can use this property  
\begin{align}
E((X_n-X_{n-1})(X_{n-1}-X_p))&=E(E((X_n-X_{n-1})(X_{n-1}-X_p)|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})) \\
& =E(\color{red}{E((X_n-X_{n-1})|\mathcal{F}_{n-1})}(X_{n-1}-X_p))\\
& =E(\color{red}0\times(X_{n-1}-X_p)) \\& = 0
\end{align}
And then $$E(X_n-X_p)^2 = E(X_n-X_{n-1})^2 +E(X_{n-1}-X_p)^2 =\sum_{i=p+1}^n E(X_i-X_{i-1})^2 $$
is straightforward

Comment: You are right and your comment made me realise that the was a typo in my line of argument but this equivalent to what I described. I will add for completeness the reason why I can write the conditioning argument in this way as it is esntially implicit in my current line of reasoning .